# How to Link a Excel Table with Access and prevent NULL Values due to wrong Data Type Conversion?

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

In the current Project i Need to Keep a Excel File which gets Values from a Machine to the Access Database to work with them and Import them in the Data Model.
Problem is some of the Values give invalid results due to the way they are saved. For example the timestamp is saved like

> 030420 instead of 03:04:20 and Access cant handle that and gives me a #NUMBER

I can not simply Change the datatype in Excel because the whole Excel gets refreshed every hour by a source that i cant influence.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you realy have to Link the file ? We have powerful yet simple `DoCmd` function to import Excel to Access table

Answer (score 1):

If Erik's proposal does not work, you can
- create a backup copy of your Excel source
- tweak the file: enter text in the first row of the problematic columns
- link the tweaked file into Access
- put back the real file in place.
Now the problematic columns should be read as Text, and you can build a query that solves any issue like conversion, null handling...

Answer (score 1):

Link, don't import, the Excel file, and you have a linked table.

Now, use this linked table as source in a simpel select query where you modify the data and alias the fields as needed. For example:

```
Select 
    F1 As SomeName, 
    F2 As OtherName, 
    TimeSerial(Mid([F5],1,2),Mid([F5],3,2),Mid([F5],5,2)) As TrueTime
From
    LinkedTable
Where
    F7 Is Not Null
```

The use this query for your import.

Answer (score 0):

Consider querying the Excel file instead of using a linked table.

The query can directly query an Excel range:

```
SELECT * FROM
[Excel 12.0 XML;DATABASE=PathToMyExcel;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1].[MyRange] t
```

Then, you can use functions like `TimeSerial` to cast numbers to time values.